# How do I get the largest 2d slice of a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3d numpy array where the dimensions are different. I would like to plot a slice parallel to the largest 2 dimensions and midway through the smallest. How do I get the slice?

e.g. if my original data is

```
np.ones(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5)
```

I would like to get the dataset

```
np.ones(3*4*5).reshape(3,4,5)[1,:,:]
```

that is halfway though the first dimension as it is the smallest and all of the other two dimensions because they are larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.rollaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) for such a task and that would work for any multi-dimensional ndarray, like so -

```
def ndim_largest_slice(arr):
    shp = arr.shape
    return np.rollaxis(arr, np.argmin(shp), 0)[shp[np.argmin(shp)]/2]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [511]: arr = np.random.rand(6,7,6,3,4,5)

In [512]: np.allclose(ndim_largest_slice(arr),arr[:,:,:,1,:,:])
Out[512]: True

In [513]: arr = np.random.rand(6,7,6,4,5,5)

In [514]: np.allclose(ndim_largest_slice(arr),arr[:,:,:,2,:,:])
Out[514]: True

In [515]: arr = np.random.rand(3,4,5)

In [516]: np.allclose(ndim_largest_slice(arr),arr[1,:,:])
Out[516]: True
```